# Set default to Not Selected Bootstrap country picker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

With [Bootstrap country picker](https://mojoaxel.github.io/bootstrap-select-country/index.html), I am using the code below to populate countries. Its working fine but there is no "Not Selected" default. Is there a work around for this...?

```
<script>
  $('.countrypicker').countrypicker();
</script>

    <select class="form-control selectpicker countrypicker" id="country" name="country" data-flag="true" data-default=""></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the text 'Nothing Selected', set the title property to whatever you need.

eg: title="My Custom Text"

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker countrypicker" id="country" name="country" data-flag="true" title="My Custom Text"></select>
<button>Add option</button>
```